# Universal approximation theorem for injections

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, machine-learning, approximation-theory, neural-networks

Let $\sigma$ be a non-polynomial continuous [activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function). The classical [universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem#Arbitrary-width_case) says that functions of the form $f(x) = C\sigma(Ax + b)$ can approximate any continuous function from a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}^D$.

Is there a similar class of *[injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)* that can approximate any continuous *injection* from a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}^D$? For example, would it suffice to constrain $\sigma$ in some way and constrain $CA$ to be injective? If so, how could the latter constraint be achieved in a way that allows all parameters to be optimized through [gradient descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent), while retaining universality?

A [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164034/injectivity-of-a-linear-logistic-transform) was asked many years ago, but did not receive an answer.

Comment: I think it's difficult to satisfy the injectivity by the given form. It is because, mostly the activation function $\sigma$ is nondecreasing (and if it's strictly increasing, it would be better for injectivity). In this situation, if $f$ is injective, at least $Ax+b$ should be injective as well. The affine transform $Ax+b$ seems not to be injective in general.